# How to translate "to catch a bus"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Some people translate it as *kapti buson*, but that seems to be an anglicism. The bus does not become less free, since you are only using it. What is the most normal way to say it?

Answer (score 6):

Trafi. I understand the word to mean (figuratively rather than literally) "to hit" (the mark), "to strike" (gold) or "to catch" (the bus).

Comment: And by the way, I think mondano's answer of atingi is also correct, I just think trafi is more specific.

Comment: This is logical if you remember that _maltrafi_ is very common to mean you missed the bus. However I wonder if you would only use _trafi_ if there was an expectation you might have missed the bus and you want to report your success? If it has the same meaning as _atingi_ it would be weird to say “Kiel vi iros al la koncerto? Mi trafos / atingos buson”.

Comment: I was pondering this last night as I was settling into bed (yes really) and came to the same answer - *trafi*. It's the opposite of *maltrafi trajnon* which is an attested phrase. I didn't get out of bed to post and you beat me to it. It's also attested in the *Tekstaro* (Iu malriĉulino volas trafi la trajnon) - along with, interestingly, *kapti trajnon* and *atingi trajnon*. The one thing I would add to this answer is that the translation doesn't need to be of the form "[Verb]-i buson." You could also say, for example, "mia trajno tuj venos" or "mi devas rapidi por mia trajno."

Answer (score 5):

*Atingi* kaj *preni* estas tute bonaj vortoj, same *kapti*, sed ĉiu havas sian propran nuancon. *Atingi* emfazas sukceson pro alveno ĝustatempa, sufiĉe frua kaj rapida. Ĉe *kapti* iomete elstariĝas la ideo "sukcesi uzi aŭ preni por si, per iom da penado". La plej neŭtrala verbo estas *preni*. Ofte tiaj detaloj ne tre gravas, kaj eblas elekti iun ajn el la verboj aŭ tute alian vorton, kondiĉe ke ĝi ne sugestas maltaŭgan nuancon.  Ankaŭ la Angla vorto *catch* estas iom elasta, kaj foje interŝanĝebla kun *take*.

Jen por vi abundo da ekzemploj kun plej diversaj verboj, ĉiu kun sia propra nuanco. Ĉiuj estas prenitaj el la Tekstaro. Ne ĉiuj el ili taŭgas kiel tradukoj de la Angla *catch*, sed ĉiuj rilatas al utiligo de veturilo pli-malpli publika. Kelkaj frazoj devenas el tekstoj sufiĉe malnovaj, ĉar estas veturiloj jam eksmodaj, sed la verboj estas plu aktualaj.

- Plej bone estos, se mi **prenos droŝkon**!
- Pro tio la ĉerkisto donis al li dek kopekojn por vodko, rapide vestis sin, **prenis fiakron** kaj venis al Razguljaj.
- En la sama vespero la agentino **luis fiakron** kaj veturigis ŝin en la faman domon de Kitajeva.
- La plej simpla maniero atingi Kaliningradon por mi estis veturi ŝipe al Gdańsk, kaj tie **kapti buson** post duontaga atendado.
- Belardo, li diris, vi **uzos kaleŝon**, portos tiun leteron al ĝia adreso, ĝin remetos en la proprajn manojn de l’ adresato, kaj lin rekondukos al mi kun vi.
- En tiu urbo fraŭlino Delanjo **dungis kaleŝon**;
- Mi do **uzas kaleŝon** kaj ĝin lasas apud la Astronomia Observejo.
- La programo finiĝis akurate je tagmezo, post kio oni devis rapide disiĝi por **ne maltrafi pramon, aŭtobuson, aviadilon** ktp.
- Fernando rekomencis sian kuradon, **atingis la vagonaron** en momento, kiam ĝi ekmoviĝis,
- ŝi alvenis ĝustatempe por **uzi la lastan vagonaron** direktiĝantan al Parizo.
- La anglo fariĝis konfuzita kaj ekskuzis sin, ke la tempo ne permesas tian tralegon, ke li devas **kapti trajnon** k. t. p.
- Li venis precize al la stacio por **atingi la lastan trajnon** al la urbo.
- Sed kiam mi povos **preni la sekvan trajnon?**
- Li senhezite eliris, pensante: “Jen do ... Iu malriĉulino volas **trafi la trajnon**
- Mi **prenis tramon** de Stureplan kaj veturis tiel longe kiel eblis en Kungsholmen, kie mi infanaĝe
- Ili ekkuras. Je distanco de duona dombloko la policisto vidis viron kurantan por **atingi tramon**.
- La pasaĝero, por li nekonata, **prenis la tie atendantan taksion**, verŝajne li mendis la veturilon.
- Ĉiaokaze, mi trajne iris ĝis la itala marborda urbeto Bordighera, kaj tie **luis taksion** por la dudek-minuta vojaĝo al la princlando.
- Kaliningradaj esperantistoj afable renkontis min ĉe la buso, ni kune promenis en la agrabla somera vespero al bela manĝejo, kie mi povis provi la lokan bieron kaj poste **kaptis privatan taksion** por veturi al la tranoktejo.

Answer (score 2):

Atingi. Ekzemple: Mi devas atingi tiun buson.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's an anglicism, in French too you say "*attraper un bus*". That's just an imaged use of the verb, and *kapti* sounds relevant here, as according to PIV it may means "*Sukcesi atingi k firme teni iun, kiu provas forkuri*".